# vanilla - change base64 encoded image when refresh the page

Tags: javascript, base64

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">

        <style type="text/css">

            /* author css */
            body, html, .wrapper, .container {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
            .container {
                max-width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0 auto;
                position: relative;
            }

            .logo {
                width: 50%;
                display: block;
                margin: 0 auto;
                text-align: center;
                padding-top: 160px;
            }

            .error-page {
                background-position: center center;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: 100%;
                height: 100%; 
            }
            @media (max-width: 1024px) {
                .error-page {
                    background-position: center -100px;
                }
            }

            .en_lang .error-page {
                background-image: url();
            }
            @media (min-width: 1024px) {
               .en_lang .error-page {
                    background-image: url();
                }
            }

            .de_lang .error-page {
                background-image: url();
            }
            @media (min-width: 1024px) {
               .de_lang .error-page {
                    background-image: url();
                }
            }

            .fr_lang .error-page {
                background-image: url();
            }
            @media (min-width: 1024px) {
               .fr_lang .error-page {
                    background-image: url();
                }
            }

            .es_lang .error-page {
                background-image: url();
            }
            @media (min-width: 1024px) {
               .es_lang .error-page {
                    background-image: url();
                }
            }

            .it_lang .error-page {
                background-image: url();
            }
            @media (min-width: 1024px) {
               .it_lang .error-page {
                    background-image: url();
                }
            }

            .br_lang .error-page {
                background-image: url();
            }
            @media (min-width: 1024px) {
               .br_lang .error-page {
                    background-image: url();
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body class="en_lang">
        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="error-page">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to make a simple script to automatically change my background image in a random way when I refresh the page.

I must specify few things:

1. The images are encoded as base64;
2. I cannot use external assets
3. I have to use vanilla javascript

You can take a look here de.istefan.ro (adult content)

For now I use only this code to alocate proper image to the proper user language select:

```
(function() {
    // check url and add the language class to the body tag
    var className = window.location.host.split('.')[0];
    className = (className =='istefan')? 'en_lang' : className+'_lang';

    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].setAttribute('class', className );
})();
```

Thank you guys.

Comment: So, what did you tried according to these specifications ?

Comment: Show your code, not a link to a not relevant external site. And precise what part exactly is a problem for you. Do you for example know how to set a background in JS ? Did you search for that part ?

Comment: Im tryin but I got "oh snap" from chrome because I use about 4 desktop pictures with 4 mobile in base64 so the code is so long

Comment: Okay, there is two smart/cheat solutions for your use case, if I corrently undertood you - AppCache manifest and Service workers. Support is differenced by browsers, but via polyfills it will work in every modern browser. At first run just download all image assets in real URL path, and later just request in from offline manifest, and you don't need base64 conversion. You can easily take fast start from create-react-app, in which it included in-the-box.

Comment: Thank you Vladislav but I really dont know how to use service workers :(